# Working with big numbers pstricks

Tags: graphics, pstricks, pstricks-add, geogebra

I'm trying to plot some functions, for this I'm using Geogebra for generating the graphics, the following is the generated code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=5pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-1.0067539097747136E9,-1.986947150681829)(1.1007960524213434E10,44.984471028928745)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,Dx=1.E9,Dy=5.,ticksize=-2pt 0,subticks=2]{->}(0,0)(-1.0067539097747136E9,-1.986947150681829)(1.1007960524213434E10,44.984471028928745)
\psplot[linewidth=1.2pt,plotpoints=200]{-1.0067539097747136E9}{1.1007960524213434E10}{0.01469486445931648*1.0000000008464012^(x)}
\begin{scriptsize}
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](1000.,0.001)
\rput[bl](7.17057308637737E7,0.36162375829869975){\darkgray{$A$}}
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](10000.,9.20790000000001E-4)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](100000.,0.00161386)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](1000000.,0.00507920000000001)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](1.E7,0.0467228000000001)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](1.E8,0.42999023)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](1.E9,4.17982101)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](1.E10,41.6545143100001)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](1000.,0.001)
\rput[bl](7.17057308637737E7,0.36162375829869975){\darkgray{$A$}}
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](10000.,9.20790000000001E-4)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](100000.,0.00161386)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](1000000.,0.00507920000000001)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](1.E7,0.0467228000000001)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](1.E8,0.42999023)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](1.E9,4.17982101)
\psdots[dotsize=3pt 0,dotstyle=*,linecolor=darkgray](1.E10,41.6545143100001)
\rput[bl](-2.354828460572823E9,-0.9078740303394239){$f$}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

But when I try to compile I get the following error

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> E
l.6 ...)(1.1007960524213434E10,44.984471028928745)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot...

Comment: Warmest welcome to TeX.SE! Great first question.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
\psdot(! 1.1007960524213434E10 44.984471028928745)
```

Then it will be read as PostScript coordinates. However, for the environment `pspicture` and the macro `\psplot` you have to change the coordinates. But the export from Geogebra is complete unusable!